# URL unreachable without error

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I've updated my site with OG meta information, but it's not working perfectly. On this portal some article is unreachable for Facebook (Comments say about it). But when I paste URL in FB status, it can't load initial image and teaser for this article. This problem is not permanent, but too often to make me sad. Clicking on the link takes me to the developers.facebook.com/tools/lint? page, and can't say any error, everything seems to be fine. What can I do, can anybody help me?
Some URLs for checking (clicking on the debug page the error message disappear, and everything will be fine):

http://www.femcafe.hu/cikkek/celeb/jessica-simpson-2-millio-dollaros-szulese

http://www.femcafe.hu/cikkek/celeb/nem-haragszom-markra-interju-eden-kiraval

If you need more URLs, I can send more.

Comment: [More link #1](http://www.femcafe.hu/cikkek/celeb/kituntettek-az-anima-sound-system-et)
[More link #2](http://www.femcafe.hu/cikkek/divat/vintage-lelohelyek)
[More link #3](http://www.femcafe.hu/cikkek/ezo/szombaton-szuperhold-lesz)
[More link #4](http://www.femcafe.hu/cikkek/recept/keszits-nudlit)

Comment: [More link #5](http://www.femcafe.hu/cikkek/recept/nap-receptje-tejszines-lazackremleves)

Comment: [More link #6](http://www.femcafe.hu/cikkek/celeb/harry-herceg-idegesiti-kate-et-es-vilmost)

Answer (score 1):

The new link for *lint* is :

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Make sure you don't have any redirects on your pages/links, it will scrape the last/final url.

Check if you have any cache issues etc.

I don't see any errors

Comment: you're right, i've mistyped the developers URL. I have no redirects on this URLs, I wrote the final URLs. Flushing cache doesn't solve the problem. Thanks for spenting time to check my problem.